# Suggested Journals or Publications for Staying Current on Data Science?

Tags: python, data-science

I was wondering if anyone recommends a reputable publication on the latest and greatest in data science and Python. I know that there are blogs like Quora or Stack Overflow, but I was hoping to find something more established and/or vetted like what the Wall Street Journal would be for finance, Sports Illustrated for sports or The New York Times for general news.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. Se [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There's this _theory-focused_, peer-reviewed journal that I'd actually recommend for how thorough and surprisingly interactive it is: https://distill.pub/ but it doesn't fit as a means for "hot topic updates". Still worth reading.

Comment: Anything is appreciated. Thanks, Julio!